# CSS problems in all browsers

Tags: css

I am trying to add social media icons to the footer of canopyco.com, but am having difficulty with the CSS.

Here are my problems:

1. The icons are aligned properly in Chrome and Safari, but in IE and FF, they are not.  This is because in IE and FF, the footer link text is larger than in Chrome and Safari, therefore the margins that I've set up for the icons do not work.  The icons should be flush with the left side of the footer navigation links.
2. When I place the icons in the footer, somehow the icons div is covering up the footer navigation links text.

I'm pretty fresh in CSS still, so I'm hoping someone here can guide me.  I don't want to post the code here in the question, as there is a LOT of CSS and HTML to take into account when looking at the bugs.

Comment: Or screenshots, or a publicly available demo site would help.

Comment: I put the link to the live site in the first line of the question.  

I can't post the code here, as it seems to be breaking the formatting of the site when I do.

Comment: If i check out your site in FF with the Firebug addon (<< recommended for debugging css) and I disable the margins on the individual IMG items (26px 20px) in the UL with id="footer_icons" then it seems those are the ones causing the off position. Hope that will help you debug. (edited: moved to a comment on the initial post, this isnt quite an answer)

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting your html, here is what you should do:

Get rid of `height` in the footer nav and set `overflow` to `hidden`

```
#footer ul#footer_nav {
 margin-top: 23px;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also get rid of `height` in the footer icons and set `overflow` to `hidden`

```
#footer ul#footer_icons {
 margin-top: -3px;
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 width: 200px;
 margin-left: -2px;
 overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the icons overwriting the link text.  Now I just have to fix the alignment of the icons in relation to the text in IE and FF.